# How can I add very large numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, biginteger, largenumber

How can I add very large numbers in C++?

Comment: This question is repeated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c

Comment: Numbers are not necessarily ints so it may not be exactly the same.

Comment: Also Check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=BigInt+c%2B%2B

Comment: If you want to perform the multi-precision math yourself, then I suggest you take a look at Donald Knuth's [Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming). I believe Volume II, Seminumerical Algorithms, Chapter 4, Multiple Precision Arithmetic, is what you are interested in. Also see [How to add 2 arbitrarily sized integers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2926219/608639), which provides code for some C++ libraries and OpenSSL.

Answer (score 3):

consider a "bignum" library like: http://gmplib.org/ or http://ttmath.slimaczek.pl/ttmath. take a look at a simple bignum class: http://www.circlemud.org/~jelson/560/

Answer (score 1):

Do a Google on "Bigint C++" This will provide you with a list of arbitrator precision integer arithmetic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a big decimal implementation at http://speleotrove.com/decimal/

Answer (score 0):

How big is "very large"?  A signed long int can go up to 2,147,483,647 and an unsigned long int can go up to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: Not accurate sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int). So technically long only has to be as big as int (and on most systems nowadays is just 32). long long (A C extension not yet officially supported by C++) has a minimum of 64 bytes.

Comment: You mean 64 bits, not 64 bytes.

Comment: Accurate. sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int) is not the only requirement; the 32 bits range is another.

Answer (score 0):

GMP has a GMPXX C++ wrapper which is kind of nice.  GMP supports both integer and floating point numbers, and is **L**GPL'ed.

I've used it.  It's ok, but watch out for creating lots of temporaries.  (Potential efficiency hit.)

Answer (score -1):

You could use a library like [LiDIA](http://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/TI/LiDIA/) for a 'big integer' class.