# C++ string to boolean array

Tags: c++, string, binary

I have a ~100 digit string which represents a number in base 10 that I want to convert to either a string representing the number in base 2, or a bool array which represents the number's digits in binary. I can do it easily in Java using BigInteger, but I'm not sure if there is an equivalent in C++.

Function would be something like:

string toBinaryString(string numInDecimal);

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP) available at http://gmplib.org.
Then [mpz set str](http://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Integers.html#Assigning-Integers) is probably what you need to create a "BigInteger" from your string.
And [mpz get str](http://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html#Converting-Integers) to create a string again. Both functions take the base as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no standard C++ class/function to do that.
Anyway, to give you at least some little help here are some more or less useful starting points to develop your own bigInt C++ class :

[StackOverflow : How to implement big int in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c)

[SourceForge : C++ BigInt class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/)

[Matt McCutchen : BigInt Class](http://mattmccutchen.net/bigint)

Answer (score 0):

Uh... that's a hell a lot of digits in binary, and you're going to have some fun time handling it.

Either that, or you can use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) to help you along...