# why calculator and excel show value great than 2^31 -1 in 32bit systems?

Tags: operating-system, cpu

I have taken some courses in c/c++ and I understand that int type size is limited according to CPU architecture.

For 32bit the maximum value of int is `2^32` ( `4,294,967,295` ), but when I use calculator or excel i get huge number and great than `2^32` .

I am really don't understand this detail how this programs print value great great than 2^23 value .

Comment: They use larger datatypes like floating-point or bignums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use values larger than 32 bits in a  32 bit system. In fact, there are BIGINT libraries (like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)) that allow you to use *arbitrarily large* integers. These large numbers simply have to be handled in **software** rather than **hardware**.

[x86-specific example] Where a simple 32-bit addition uses the `add` instruction, which adds two 32-bit registers, a 64-bit or BIGINT addition requires the numbers to be added 32 bits *at a time*, manually propagating the carry from one addition to the next.

See also:

- [How to implement big int in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c)
- [storing big numbers in c++ or c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865903/storing-big-numbers-in-c-or-c?lq=1)

Comment: Many architectures support the adc instruction for this exact purpose.