# Which type in c++ can store 2^63?

Tags: c++

I need to store 2^63 natural number in my program. Int has 4 bytes: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/ so it is 2^(8*4) = 2^32, which type should I use?

Comment: What platform? Signed or unsigned? You may have 'long long' or 'int64_t'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c check this.

Comment: No you don't. If so tell me why?

Comment: Note that int isn't guaranteed to be 4 bytes... It just is an every modern desktop I can think of.

Comment: All integer types can store `2^63` (which is equal to 61) :p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `unsigned long long`, but I would check that your compiler supports that type.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(unsigned long long)<< " bytes" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints `8 bytes` on my machine which is enough room to store 2^63.

Answer (score 3):

This is architecture dependent. C++ doesn't have C's `stdint.h` header for guaranteed integer widths. On 64-bit linux `long` will be 64-bits.

I think C++11 adds `cstdint` as a wrapper for `stdint.h`. Then you can use `int64_t`.

**Edit:** As johannes pointed out, `long` is 32 bits in Windows. I'm not sure this can be done portably in C++03 while still maintaining full standards compliance. `long long` and `int64_t` are not a part of the C++03 standard, but are offered as compiler extensions by the common compilers.

Comment: long on win64 is 32-bits. On Unix/Linux it's 64-bit. One of the annoyances when writing portable code. As others mentioned long long, if supported is the way to go. (New in C++11)

Comment: you mean `long long`.  On Windows, `long` is 32 bits in Windows.

Comment: Corrected. I should stop making assumptions about Windows, because it always seems to defy my expectations.

Comment: @OscarKorz, that's why limits.h exposes `LONG_MAX` and `ULONG_MAX`, so you can validate your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

On most modern processors, a `long long int`.  Technically this is new to C99/C++11, but most C++ compilers have supported it since '99-ish.
Constants are the form `0LL`

Comment: I think the ll suffix is case-insensitive.

Comment: Never knew that.  Also changed the constant.  Point gets across with smaller numbers too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[GNU multiple precision arithmetic library](http://gmplib.org/manual)**

It has a **[C++ Class Interface](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface)** as well

Note:

> C++ support in GMP can be enabled with `--enable-cxx', in which case a
>   C++ compiler will be required. As a convenience`--enable-cxx=detect'
>   can be used to enable C++ support only if a compiler can be found. The
>   C++ support consists of a library libgmpxx.la and header file gmpxx.h
>   (see Headers and Libraries).

Answer (score 0):

`__int64` and `long long` are often used but not part of STL.
`long long` for C will work with GCC if `__int64` is not supported.
in C99, if you need *exactly* 64 bits you can use `int64_t`,from `<stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `*_MAX` constants defined in `limits.h` for your compiler. If any of them are >= 2^63, use the type corresponding to that constant. For my compiler, `ULLONG_MAX` is `0xffffffffffffffffi64` or `18446744073709551615`, which is >= `9223372036854775808` (2^63). So I would use `unsigned long long` as the type to hold natural numbers up to 2^63.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful, but double is capable of representing the value pow(2, 63) exactly (no error). However, it can't represent pow(2, 63) + 1.0 exactly, nor can it represent pow(2, 63) - 1.0, so that might not be a helpful answer.

So if you actually want an integer representation of it, you need to use the unsigned 64-bit integer type (the signed type is not sufficient, as (1<<63) is a negative value). Unfortunately, 64-bit integer support is widespread but not entirely standardized. I believe that "unsigned long long int" works in all current-version compilers, but your mileage may vary. I deal with the variance by having a configuration header that typedef's a "uint64" and then typedefs it differently depending on the current compiler. Once C++11 is more widely implemented, it will add "unsigned int64_t", and that will be the correct way to do it after that point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a Big Integer library for this.

Here's a public domain one which works: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long result = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 64; i++){
        if(i == 64){
            result = ((result * 2)-1);
        }
        else{
            result = ((result * 2));
        }


    }

    cout << "result is : " << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Comment: The little program  I had written above, it can store (2^64)-1 decimal number which is 18446744073709551615 and it is above then 2^63.