# Ideas for storing and operating on huge numbers in C++

Tags: c++, c

I am supposed to build a program for storing and handling huge integers. I know that there are many answers out there but I need ideas that I can implement easily, bearing in mind that I can use any of the basic concepts of C/C++.

How should I go about it?

This is the first time I am asking a question here so please correct me if I am wrong about anything.

Edit: Actually what I wanted to know was how should I go about storing a huge integer... Obviously an array is what comes to mind at first glance but are there any other methods out there at the basic level?

EDIT2: I came across a very nice solution to this problem a while ago, but was just a bit lazy to put it on here. We can use the concept of number systems to deal with huge numbers. We can declare an array that holds the co-efficient of powers of 256, thus obtaining a base 256 system. We can then use fundamental concepts like those of the  various number systems to obtain our required results.

Comment: "I have to use all the basic concepts of C/C++." - All? Sounds unrealistic...

Comment: The first thing to decide is whether you're using C or C++. They are very different languages.

Comment: I detect a project euler starter

Comment: I have to use some of the basic concepts. If the choice of language is important, let's assume I am using C++.

Comment: you need to use big numbers or implement a library that is designed to handle big numbers ?

Comment: @user2485710 : I need to design a code that can be used to handle huge integers. Similar to designing a bigInt program but using fundamentals only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt McCutchen has a [Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint)

If you want to do this yourself his code would be a great starting point.  As you can overload  arithmetic operators in C++ it is not too difficult to make a new BigInteger class and make this handle any number of bits per integer.

There is also a stack overflow answer to this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I consider this as a question about theory, as such I suggest to [browse the internet using the right keywords](http://www.google.com/#q=c+++standard+library+arbitrary+precision+integer) for documents/articles or to take a sneak peek at [libraries that are implementing this feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries) and are well tested, this projects also tend to offer a mailing list or a forum where developers can communicate, it can be a good place to start writing about this stuff.